# Tizen Wearable - tizen.time.getCurrentDateTime() vs new Date()

Tags: javascript, tizen-wearable-sdk

I noticed that on the Tizen Wearable Watch Widget Demo they use [tizen.time.getCurrentDateTime()](https://developer.tizen.org/fr/community/tip-tech/time-api-guide?langredirect=1). Is there any real benefit from using this against new Date()?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link.
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.device.apireference/tizen/time.html

This API can be used to get TZDate objects with full time zone support, convert them between timezones, retrieve available timezones.

The problem it is trying to address is as follows.
*"The JavaScript Date object does not have full timezone support. Date objects allow only simple representations to denote a particular location's offset from Universal Coordinated Time (UTC)."*

Comment: I see, I guess it depends on your needs. If you want to support multiple time zone clocks (in a watch face for example) then `tizen.time` is the way to go but if you are only using local time then `new Date()` should be fine. Is that correct?

Comment: The usage scenarios could be much broader than what is mentioned but yes, basically more flexibility in dealing with relative dates, DST settings etc. That seems to be the motivation to create tizen.time.

Comment: Yeah, it actually taps into the phone's clock, in case you set a different timezone in your phone's settings. My app actually got rejected because I did not use `tizen.time`. Whenever you switch your timezone in your phone `new Date()` does not reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

One difference I have noticed between both is that the Tizen date object (tizen.time.getCurrentDateTime()) is "synchronized" with the date object on a companion app running on your paired smartphone. For example, whenever the timezone changes on the smartphone the tizen date object reflects this change whilst the date() function does not reflect this.

For more, see http://denvycom.com/blog/gear-2-developer-tips/